# How to validate loop dynamic radio button?

Tags: javascript, php, loops, dynamic, radio-button

I'm developing some questionnaire for user to answer.
Using loop radio button, here's my code:

```
<?php
  $i4 = 1;
  while ($rows_element4 = mysql_fetch_array($result_element4)){
  ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $i4; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $rows_element4['question_bm']; ?><br/><br/><i><?php echo $rows_element4['question_bi']; ?></i></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="e4q<?php echo $i4; ?>" id="e4q<?php echo $i4; ?>" value="1" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please choose something')"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="e4q<?php echo $i4; ?>" id="e4q<?php echo $i4; ?>" value="2"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="e4q<?php echo $i4; ?>" id="e4q<?php echo $i4; ?>" value="3"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="e4q<?php echo $i4; ?>" id="e4q<?php echo $i4; ?>" value="4"></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="e4q<?php echo $i4; ?>" id="e4q<?php echo $i4; ?>" value="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  $i4++;
  }
  ?>
```

I'm not familiar with javascript / jquery.
How to validate radio button in this form so that all questions will not left blank.?

Comment: There is a reason why jQuery has documentation.

Comment: Instead of id use class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple function which will check if any radio button is not checked it will return false.

```
function isSubmissionValid(){
var isValid = true;
     if (!$("input[name='e4q']:checked").val()) {
        isValid = false;
      }
return isValid;
}
```

Now on submit button click call this function which will let you examine if any radio button is left unchecked.

```
 $('#submit_button').click(function() {
    if(isSubmissionValid())
    {
        //go ahead with form submission
    }
    else
    {
       alert("You must select all answer");
    }
 });
```

**Edit**

You can use `input[name^='e4q']` which will select all your radio [starting](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) with e4q.

Comment: as u can see my 'name' attribute is in loop. $i4 could be e4q1. e4q2, e4q3, e4q4,...till e4q10. How to apply that on function?

Comment: @Alieym then you should use jquery start with operator as I see all your radio button start with e4q.See edited ans.

Comment: it shows error on line bool isValid = true; is this javascript?

Comment: Sorry change bool to var